# How to decode JSON string values in powershell and get rid of quotes at the beginning and the end

Tags: json, regex, powershell, unicode

When I call some WCF endpoints which return single string in JSON format it is encoded, this means that all new lines has been changed to unicode entities and it is wrapped in `"`. Like that:

`"Something1\u000d\u000aSomething"`

to decode unicode entities I do:

```
[regex]::Unescape($reader.ReadToEnd())
```

but this leaves me with:

```
"Something1
Something"
```

so i am left with redundant quotes which I want get rid of.

What solution I was thinking about and **they're wrong**:

1. Take substring to exclude first and last character. This is wrong because from some WEB API endpoints I don't get these quotes.
2. Replace all `"` chars with `ReplaceAll` method. This is wrong because it will also replace quotes in the middle of the message.

Comment: If it is JSON, why not use ConvertFrom-JSON to convert it to clean data?

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld hint is preferable, but you could try to use the `.Trim()` method like this `[regex]::Unescape('"Something1\u000d\u000aSomething"'.Trim('"'))`

Comment: @LotPings Did exactly that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function:

```
function DecodeUnicodeAndTrimQuotes {
    Param ([string]$s)
    return [regex]::Unescape($s).Trim('"')
}
```

that fixed it all.